# calling .css() function disables hover

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

So I have this hover code:

```
  function shortHover(elem){
    $('body').delegate(elem, 'hover',
            function() {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#f0c723;")
            },

            function(){
                $(this).css("background-color", "#00ed00;")
            }
    )
    }

    shortHover("#for_width_my_added");
    shortHover("#for_width_my_published");
    shortHover("#for_width_my_unpublished");
```

And than, on clicking on one of these elements:

```
$("#for_width_my_added").css("background-color", "#00ed00");
$("#for_width_my_published").css("background-color", "#00ed00");
$("#for_width_my_unpublished").css("background-color", "#00ed00");
$("#for_width_<%= @output[0] %>").css("background-color", "#f0c723");
```

So on clicking over elements assigned to green color, and currently clicked - to color of hover, so one element can have these color permanentely.

The problem is that after clicks over elements stop react on hover. Even though I used delegate.
Why?

Comment: You can't use `delegate` with `hover`, it's not a real event. `delegate` only allows you to supply a single handler function for a single event. `.hover()` is a jQuery shorthand for binding `mouseIn` and `mouseOut` handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that jQuery's [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) isn't a real JavaScript event, but merely a jQuery event or shorthand for `$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`. You can use this instead:

```
function shortHover(elem) {
    $('body').delegate(elem, 'mouseover mouseout',
    function (e) {
        if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#f0c723");
        } else if (e.type == 'mouseout') {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#00ed00");
        }
    });
}

shortHover("#for_width_my_added");
shortHover("#for_width_my_published");
shortHover("#for_width_my_unpublished");

$("#for_width_my_added").css("background-color", "#00ed00");
$("#for_width_my_published").css("background-color", "#00ed00");
$("#for_width_my_unpublished").css("background-color", "#00ed00");
$("#for_width_<%= @output[0] %>").css("background-color", "#f0c723");
```

And here's a <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4AjLw/)</kbd>

Unless you are using an older version of jQuery, you shouldn't use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) but use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead as it has superseded [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).